# double diverge series $\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } z^{j+k} \Gamma (j+k+1)$

Tags: calculus

I am curious about the series$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } z^{j+k} \Gamma (j+k+1)$$
that is clearly divergent, I thought that it could be sum with the regularization of Borel but it did not work, I have tried to use Maple but for the value  of $z=-1$ it gives $0.980631978620035457$ a value that I think is wrong must be using asymtotic calculation approximately $0.40365263767680592549535958549905$
could check this values, I know that Mathematica uses the Levin transform but gives error values for some series.
I give some values if someone could check it

[image]

Comment: yes @Mariusz Iwaniuk but the result it is correct for a simple sum $$\text{Sum}\left[z^j \Gamma (j+1),\{j,0,\infty \},\text{Regularization}\to \text{Borel}\right]=-\frac{e^{-1/z} \Gamma \left(0,-\frac{1}{z}\right)}{z}$$

Comment: sorry I have correct and error in the series

Comment: Thanks but i have find a solution $$-\frac{e^{-1/z} \left(e^{1/z}+\frac{\Gamma \left(0,-\frac{1}{z}\right)}{z}\right)}{z}$$